# semen on clothes after washing impure?

Tags: ghusl, najis

Please advise me with one thing, I had wet dream at night, I woke up took ghusl and went on with my day and when I came back my mum washed those impure bottoms, I wore & sometime later found that there's still stain of impurity from the wet dream.

Questions: is the bottom still impure& do I have to wash it again? (Note it's already washed, not in washing machine but with detergent)

- do I have to do ghusl if I find the stain on clothes even  after washing it?

Note: the clothes part where stain is still little rusty

Comment: This question is already answered in [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/67552/semen-stains-remaining-on-clothes-even-after-thoroughly-washing-the-garment)